# Appengine python The API call mail.Send() took too long to respond and was cancelled

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

We receive this error quite frequently from our appengine application. Are other people receiving this error? Does anyone know how to get around it?

```
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/mail.py", line 894, in send
  make_sync_call('mail', self._API_CALL, message, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 94, in MakeSyncCall
return stubmap.MakeSyncCall(service, call, request, response)
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 308, in MakeSyncCall
rpc.CheckSuccess()
File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_rpc.py", line 133, in CheckSuccess
raise self.exception
DeadlineExceededError: The API call mail.Send() took too long to respond and was cancelled.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was getting a lot of those errors (on Python 2.5), I decided to move the SendMail call to a task. This way I at least get a retry each time it fails.

Comment: thanks for that - I guess I was hoping the API would take care of that rather than me!

Comment: @Richard retry at the API level is most of the time a bad idea

Comment: @ShayErlichmen - why? shouldn't sending the email be a "send and forget" mission these days? I am hitting the ```The API call mail.Send() took too long to respond and was cancelled``` error once in a while and there is nothing to do?

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the `make_sync_call` method to create a more lenient deadline.

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7610076)